# Formula to calculate total duty hours

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

How do I find the total working hours of the below driver?

```
Duty code    Dep.Time    Arri.Time
A001         03:35        04:20
A001         04:35        05:20
A001         05:51        06:20
A001         06:40        07:20
A001         09:40        10:20
```

Total Working Hour: 10:20-03:35 = 06:45hrs

Is there a formula to find the total working hours of a single person or a single duty card?

Comment: You would need a helper column that finds the number of minutes for each row, and then you just add them up and puts them in the format you need, which is technically a TimeSpan (that VBA does not support) but you can use a Date/Time variable as long as it never is more than 24 hours. This also assumes those are formatted date/time values already and not just strings in the cell.

Comment: Examples are on here to show how to calculate across midnight.

Comment: To get the result you ask for, use `MAXIFS` and `MINIFS` - ( Max arrival time - MIin departure  time, where Duty = required code)  Note that if times span midnight, then entered times should include date (even if date isn't displayed). If they don't then it gets a lot more complicated

Comment: @James FYI I addressed the midnight issue in my comment - _if times span midnight, then entered times should include date_ . If that is done, Min/Max will work fine. Whether the OP has or is willing to do that, only they can answer.

Comment: @Chris fyi - sumproduct doesn't necessarily require extra data- see update. Over and out on this one!

Comment: i.e. additional data requirement making it an inferior solution.  You've got lot's of votes and imagine you have some decent experience in excel - I've been using this product from before it was Excel - Lotus 123; that's 3 decades . Be more open to other solutions, it's not the end of the day if someone else's approach outscores yours (especially if its undoubtedly superior).  Regardless, respect should work both ways. So good on you for an honest attempt. J

Answer (score 2):

If you only have one Duty Code as in the example, you can use the MAX and MIN functions to calculate the total hours.

[image]

If you have more than one Duty Code, you can use MAXIFS and MINIFS.

[image]

Comment: Function reports total duration from when work commenced on Duty A001, and the final time - what happens if there were breaks? E.g. 1 minute was spent on Duty Code A001 at crack of dawn, and then 1 more minute just before midnight (in the context of a single day to illustrate..), then working time would be 2 mins, not ~24 hrs.  I think the Q could be worded better so don't take this as being too critical; your soln is parsimonious and reconciles to the given number - but I'm not sure this helps to find "the total working hours" per Q...